# How to find multi-word synonyms?

Tags: string-manipulation, machine-learning, natural-language, linguistics, semantic-matching

I’m looking to write a semantic distance function for phrases (5 words or less) that can map multi-word synonyms together. My domain is e-commerce fashion - here are some required examples for a solution:

1. *“Red shoes”* would be close to *“Orange sandals”*
2. *“Blue leopard purse”* would be close to *“violet spotted handbag”*

Here's the type of data that I'm starting with, a static list of synonyms:

```
exampleSyns = CloudGet @ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/832467b7-87d8-4544-a0ba-3b461a9a4e99";
```

[image]

**Approaches I've tried**

I have tried the obvious thing of using the distance of BERT vectors, but this doesn’t work well enough at the moment.

Are lists of synonyms and antonyms built-in somewhere? If so we could use them, but this seems like a general enough problem that there are probably easier approaches that I don’t know of.

I’m sure there’s an easier approach to handling this problem in Mathematica that people in NLP could help with.

**Related & References**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680278/multi-word-synonym-search-in-solr
- https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html
- http://lingo.stanford.edu/pubs/WP-2001-03.pdf
- http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2018/pdf/36.pdf

Comment: Can you share your BERT code? That would have been my first guess as well.

Comment: `NetPairEmbeddingOperator[NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[],LongShortTermMemoryLayer[],SequenceLastLayer[]}]`

Comment: I basically concatenate the last and layers from Bert for each word and then average them to get a vector distance comparison

Comment: Using a large enough text corpus can provide these kind of synonyms. Do you want to deal with large text data, or you just want to utilize some database or a trained neural network?

Comment: Presumably both or whatever is most readily available.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I added an example of the type of starting data I have - I would like to parse a given text search to return resulting product that match and multiword synonyms not yet on the list of synonyms

Comment: @M.R. I plan to post an answer after two-three days.

Comment: @AntonAntonov excellent! Thanks

Comment: @AntonAntonov two-three or twenty three? ;)

Comment: My problem is finding text data that is both accessible and provides easy to interpret results.

Comment: What about my dataset and `Synonyms /@ WordData[]`

Comment: @AntonAntonov Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot about, this thanks for reminding me. I will try using AirBnB listings and/or reviews from here: http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html .

Comment: I didn’t want to waste the bounty

Comment: @AntonAntonov I have only 10 hours to award the bounty... if you had any ideas at all, now's the time ;)

Comment: I am presenting a Quantile regression live-coding session today... I will keep the 10h limit in mind.

Comment: @M.R.There are too many parts to be explained in the answer I am preparing. I might have to do a separate post (in Community or WordPress) that explains the data ingestion. Are the results shown in my preliminary answer close to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

*(Extended comment, not an answer. From the comments to it by OP I do no see the point expanding it further into full blown answer. Thanks to everyone who reacted to it...)*

### Procedure outline

1. Ingest text data.

   - I used Air BnB review data from this site : http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html .
   - Approx. 16000 reviews. (Out of ~500K from Austin, TX and Fort Lauderdale, FL.)
   - [Here is the corresponding notebook in Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1835575).
2. Make a 
   [`LSAMon`](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2019/09/13/a-monad-for-latent-semantic-analysis-workflows/)
   object with sentence granularity level.
3. Find topics.

   - It is important to use the syntagmatic perspective.
4. Using the topics find word pairs that appear adjacent to each other in text.
5. Consider speeding up that process with:

   - a proper recommender, or
   - a prefix tree with frequencies for word pairs.
6. Select popular enough phrases.
7. Tokenize the text with the found 2-word phrases.
8. Make a second `LSAMon` object with sentence granularity level.
9. Find phrases statistical thesauri.

   - Using the paradigmatic perspective.

### Result

Here is a screenshot of Step 9 results:

[image]

```
Values[
 Map[Pick[#, StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ "→" ~~ __]] &, tblThesaurus]]
```

Here is text version of the phrase thesaurus:

```
(* {{"beautiful→view", "spacious→home"},
    {"convenient→location", "great→value", "wonderful→time"},
    {"cute→neighborhood", "accommodating→hosts"},
    {"great→place", "great→stay", "perfect→location"},
    {"highly→recommend", "great→location", "quiet→neighborhood", "perfect→location", "walking→distance", "great→place"},
    {"host→canceled", "automated→posting"},
    {"nice→place", "super→close", "beautiful→house", "excellent→location"},
    {"perfect→location", "loved→staying", "quiet→neighborhood", "really→enjoyed", "great→hosts", "short→drive", "awesome→location"},
    {"time→staying", "excellent→hosts", "wonderful→hosts"},
    {"walking→distance", "great→stay", "short→walk", "easy→access", "fort→lauderdale", "super→clean", "short→drive"}} *)
```

Comment: The bounty is doubled because it ran out, please add more complete answer if possible

Comment: What is LSAMon? Can you use BERT or any neural approach?

Comment: `LSAMon` is a package / software monad for dimension reduction. Its use in the described procedure can be replaced with word2vec or BERT. It is most likely I am not going to post here the complete solution, but in Community. (Within a day or two...)

Comment: Can you address the multiword examples in the post please: {"Red shoes”, “Orange sandals”, “Blue leopard purse”, “violet spotted handbag”}

Comment: Monads are just design patterns right? How would you BERT here, not clear at all to me... If you could add that in here it would be helpful, then I'll read your post on w-community.

Comment: could you post a link to your answer from the other site please

Comment: Also I checked and monads have nothing to do with the question

Comment: @M.R. "Also I checked and monads have nothing to do with the question" -- you simply do not understand. A "software monad" is just a software design pattern. I guarantee to you that people do use monads when dealing with neural networks.

Comment: @M.R. "Can you address the multiword examples in the post please: {"Red shoes”, “Orange sandals”, “Blue leopard purse”, “violet spotted handbag”} "  -- Why? You need to clarify in your question that those are not just examples but required evaluation phrases. From your comments to this answer it seems to me that there is no point providing further details for the outlined procedure.

Comment: Ok I updated the question, thanks, I haven’t seen monads mentioned in the ml literature but there are so many papers that I might have missed them?!

Comment: I accepted it, but it looks like there is some code (step 9), could you post it or otherwise where might we find that?

Comment: Or maybe that community link?

Comment: "I accepted it [...]" -- thanks, but maybe you should not have? :) It would be interesting other people to post answers.

Comment: You are right, I'll unaccept for now and see. But what about your code sample if you have one or a link?

Comment: I almost done with the corresponding notebook.

Comment: oh ok, thanks, no rush